# how to embed a xib into storyboard?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I'm wandering around to figure out if there's a way to embed a pre-designed xib file into storyboard in Xcode4.  Is it possible? Should I do it programmatically? If possible, where can I find a tutorial for it?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.:: Not nib. It's xib. Sorry.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

no, it's not possible to mix storyboards and nibs/xibs. storyboards are a whole new way of doing things.

EDIT: apparently you CAN mix them. i'm not sure where i read that you couldn't. sorry about that.

Comment: You can create projects that have both a storyboard and a set of nibs.