# Storyboards and nibs compatible?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, xcode4, storyboard

Can I use storyboards for all of my app, and then have one nib that it pushes to, or is the two being used at the same time not possible?

Comment: no, it is not possible to mix them

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8661818/how-to-embed-a-xib-into-storyboard

Comment: That page says you can mix them....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The storyboards and nibs can go together in one app, but if your deployment target is below iOS 5, then it won't work. The storyboards will only work on iOS 5.x.

And of course, you'd need to write code yourself to push a nib.

Answer (score 2):

[WWDC 2011 Videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/)

Session 309 - Introducing Interface Builder Storyboarding

36:00 API
41:00 Adoption (including incremental adoption)

And, as mentioned, it's iOS 5.x and higher only.