# How to handle seque if we use storyboard and use external XIBs

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.2

In story board we just right drag the button to it's destination and create a seque.

What about if I have external XIBs for all those viewControllers in storyboard? I can't drag the button again. The button is in external XIBs, not in storyboard anymore.

So what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should to create an IBOutlet for this button. For example, it's name "buttonPressed". And then implement this method.

```
- (IBOutlet)buttonPressed
{
    YourViewController *yourViewController = [[YourViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:yourViewController animated:YES]; 

}
```

Comment: That's the pre ios5 ways to do this. What about if I want seque, animation, etc.

Comment: You can use segues only with Storyboards. If you work with external XIBs in isn't possible. But you can use custom animation. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406037/custom-animation-for-pushing-a-uiviewcontroller) can help you I think.

Comment: Can I do this hybrid. Some view controllers got story board and the other use external XIB?

Comment: I think, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521714/storyboards-and-nibs-compatible) is exatcly what you are looking for